Driver disability placard when traveling in Germany as a tourist
I have a friend from Uruguay visiting who has limited mobility. He is able to drive regular cars with automatic transmission. He has a disabled licence plate in his home country and when traveling in the USA he got a Disabled Person Parking Permit.
He will be traveling to Germany and renting a car there. Is there a way he can get disabled parking access?

Of which country is your friend a citizen? Related: Germany has adopted the EU Model Parking Card

Thank you! I see the information on this website you shared. However, I can't find this information in any Stadtverwaltung specifically.

You should look for the administrative unit "Straßenverkehrsbehörde" and the term "Parkausweis für Schwerbehinderte". Here is the relevant web page for Berlin.

I searched them already, there's no info for non-residents.

Since you say you have the friend visiting you are presumably in Germany. I'd try your local Stadtverwaltung (talking to them already in advance, possibly with a photo of the Uruguay paperwork/license plate). Note that in Germany the permit is bound to the person, not to the car (i.e, a disabled person can be brought by someone in the latter's car and they use the disabled parking spot by leaving the permit visibly in the car).
